# Plot rendering error in R because of temporary directory

Tags: r, plot, directory, temporary

I was trying to make a plot in R while gettint an error:

```
dea.plot(x[,1], y[,1])
```

> ```
> Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In gzfile(file, "wb") :
>   cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/Seb? Marianna/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOSXdEz/rs-graphics-93857b8b-470a-4748-95f9-f44791f12765/4581291c-667d-4eeb-bad4-28b5904e12b4.snapshot', 
>          probable reason 'Invalid argument'
> Graphics error: Plot rendering error
> ```

I figured the problem is with my name at the temporary directory (?) and I was trying to change it with

```
write("TMPDIR = C:/Users/Marianna/AppData/Local",
      file=file.path(Sys.getenv('R_USER'), '.Renviron'))
```

but I am still getting the error

> ```
> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
>   cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
>   cannot open file 'C:/Users/Seb? Marianna/OneDrive/Documents/.Renviron': Invalid argument
> Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In gzfile(file, "wb") :
>   cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/Seb? Marianna/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOSXdEz/rs-graphics-93857b8b-470a-4748-95f9-f44791f12765/4b8b99c8-1ca3-4213-b383-a83bae51bca9.snapshot', probable reason 'Invalid argument'
> Graphics error: Plot rendering error
> ```

Comment: On my windows machine, there is some periodic clean-up job that removes old temporary directories. For me, this means that periodically what R used yesterday as a tempdir is no longer there, so many functions that rely on it will fail. For me, fixing the *symptom* by recreating the directory was generally sufficient (though not fixing the underlying cause).

Comment: I think I could not change it. That is why I got: Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w". But even if I delete it R creates a new one (I changed the environment in windows control panel)

Comment: Not sure if you understand my point, since deleting the directory will trigger the error. If any directories leading up to intended temporary files do not exist (such as when windows thoughtfully cleans up temp dirs), then anything trying to create temp files (functions that use `tempfile()` or `tempdir()`) *will fail*. Perhaps try `tempdir(check=TRUE)` and rerun the code that just failed.

Comment: I just managed to fix this issue on my machine (Windows 10). I had to pause OneDrive as this project was currently being synced constantly which I presumed messed up the permissions.